# Javascript else loop executing after if loop executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index.js file with API's that upload a gameData model to a mongoDB:`

```js
var gameValue = require('../models/gameValues');

router.post('/add_game_to_dB', function(req, res, next) {
    newGame = new gameValue(req.body);
    newGame.save(function (err, game) {
        if (err)
            throw err;

        res.json({
            "id": game._id
        });
    });
});
```

Then I have a .js file that takes detected if a button id clicked and uploads the game to the database:

```js
$("#upVoteBattlefieldOne").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name);
  var newGameName = $("#BattlefieldOne .panel-heading").text();
  newGameToDatabase(newGameName);
});

$("#upVoteBatmanTheEnemyWithin").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name);
  var newGameName = $("#BatmanTheEnemyWithin .panel-heading").text();
  newGameToDatabase(newGameName);
});

function newGameToDatabase(name) {
  $.get("/get_gameValues", function(data) {
    if (data.length == 0) {
      $.post("/add_game_to_dB", {
        gameName: name
      }, function(result) {
        alert("Upvoted " + name);
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (name === data[i].gameName) {
        alert("game is in database already");
        return;
      } else {
        $.post("/add_game_to_dB", {
          gameName: name
        }, function(result) {
          alert("Upvoted " + name);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The javascript seems to work for the first game I click. For example, if I click battlefield one, it adds it to the database if its not already there. After battlefield one is on the database, it detects that the document with the name attribute of "battlefield one" is on the database and alerts the user that the game is already in the database. Once I click on the other game i.e batman the enemy within, it adds that other game to the database if its not already there. If I click on the button to add that game(batman the enemy within) to the database again, it acknowledges that the game is on the database, but then it adds the game to the database again. It executes the if loop on line 23, and also executes the else loop as well. I tried to include a return statement to exit out of the function if the if loop conditions are met, but it seems to ignore this return statement and execute that else loop anyways. The reverse happens if I click on batman, then battlefield one has this issue. I'm new to node js and javascript so I might be making a silly mistake, but I've looked at this for a long time and I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Try using loose equality instead of strict equality when testing your name value. i.e. `if(name == data[i].gameName) {`

Comment: Also `name` comes from `$.text`. You may want to `trim` that before passing it over: **`newGameToDatabase(newGameName.trim());`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use variable for mark existing state and use break in loop.

```js
function newGameToDatabase(name) {
  $.get("/get_gameValues", function(data) {
    var alreadyExist = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (name === data[i].gameName) {
        alert("game is in database already");
        alreadyExist = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!alreadyExist) {
      $.post("/add_game_to_dB", {
        gameName: name
      }, function(result) {
        alert("Upvoted " + name);
      });
    }
  });
}
```